# Unity 3d Forge Networking: Transfer object ownership

Tags: unity, networking

I have a simple chess game setup to play around with the Forge Networking asset.  I am having an issue where only the server is able to click and drag pieces around the board.  If a client attempts to move a piece, it gets snapped back to its original position.

I assume this issue is because the server is the actual owner of the `NetworkedMonoBehaviour` components on my chess pieces.  Is it possible to transfer ownership of a `NetworkedMonoBehaviour` in code?  It seems that all of the owner properties have protected set methods so I am unable to access any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you have objects already in the scene in Forge Networking it is automatically owned by the server.  Any objects that are instantiated by the client is owned by the client.  Something you can do is either spawn the objects on the client or you can use an RPC call to move the object.  So you would move the piece and drop it, then when you drop it you would send an RPC call to place it and the server can then validate. Transferring ownership is something that has been requested in the system a couple of times and it is on the feature add list for future versions.  :)